# Validating XML with an in-memory DTD in C using libxml2

Tags: xml-parsing, dtd, libxml2

I need to validate XML using DTD stored in memory, i.e. something like the following:

```c
static const char *dtd_str = "<!ELEMENT ...>";
xmlDtdPtr dtd;

dtd = xmlParseMemoryDtd(dtd_str);
```

`XML_PARSE_DTDVALID` parser option allows to validate DTD embedded into XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE some_tag[
<!ELEMENT some_tag ...>
...
]>
<some_tag>...</some_tag>
```

So a workaround is to modify in-memory XML. Things become more complicated with
a parser used in "push mode". In push mode we have to detect whether the XML
declaration (`<?xml ...?>`), or start of the root element, then put our inline
DTD between them.

Could you suggest better solution?

**EDIT**

A workaround is to validate parsed XML posteriori as Daniel(_DV) suggested below.
Example: [main.c](http://bpaste.net/show/124241/), [response.xml](http://bpaste.net/show/124243/).

But I was searching for way to "embed" a DTD and validate XML "on-the-fly" while libxml2 parses XML chunk-by-chunk.
The following aproach doesn't work for me:

```c
xmlCtxtUseOptions(ctxt, XML_PARSE_NOENT | XML_PARSE_NOWARNING | XML_PARSE_DTDVALID);

ctxt->sax->internalSubset = ngx_http_file_chunks_sax_internal_subset;
ctxt->sax->externalSubset = NULL;
```

```
$ ./parsexml 
validity error : Validation failed: no DTD found !
<response>
         ^
Document is not valid
```

Answer (score 0):

xmlValidateDtd allows to do DTD validation a posteriori of an already parsed XML document
to make sure it validates against the DTD. This will *not* use the internal subset...
http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-valid.html#xmlValidateDtd

See xmllint.c code in libxml2 for a full example of how to use it,

Daniel

Comment: I thought of something like the following: http://bpaste.net/show/124239/
*EDIT*(sorry): But it didn't work for me. It complains about not found DTD subset.
However, the post validation works just fine.

Comment: I've added some explanation to the post.